# Trying to Multiple two columns in pervasive db (Industrios), getting syntax error

Tags: pervasive-sql

In the following Query in (Pervasive Control Center), I am trying to do a simple multiplication of two fields `l.qtyordered` x `l.unitpricet` as ExtPrice. Something I do all day long in MS SQL, but in PSQL it doesn't appear that it is the same format. Your help is appreciated. both are decimals in the db, so it shouldn't be a data type issue. I have tried using `Sum()`, tried `cast()` to change each, but nothing is working.

```
--Open Orders Line
select distinct h.ordernumber, h.orderstatus, h.customerkey, h.customername, h.shiptokey,
 h.shiptoName, h.shiptostate, h.orderdate, h.requestdate, h.customerponumber, h.salespersonkey,
  l.itemkey, l.itemdescription, l.desc2, (l.qtyordered) x (l.unitprice) as ExtPrice
 from "OEHDR_DBM" h
Left join oelin_dbm l ON l.sysdocid = h.sysdocid
where h.orderstatus not in ('C','S','QW','QP','QN')
and l.qtyremaining >0
Group by h.ordernumber, h.orderstatus, h.customerkey, h.customername,h.shiptokey, 
h.shiptoName, h.shiptostate, h.orderdate, h.requestdate, h.customerponumber, h.salespersonkey, 
l.itemkey, l.itemdescription, l.desc2, l.qtyordered, l.unitprice
--having count(h.ordernumber) =1
Order by h.Requestdate
```